# Error when sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, command-line, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I type `sudo apt-get upgrade` into the terminal I get this error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

How can  I force upgrade?

Comment: Just to make sure - have you done apt-get update properly first? Also - maybe check that libc-bin which seems to be a problem? Is it installed, what version etc.?

Comment: Try executing this command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get install libc-bin && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says using the flag -f. That's an option. But you can also use this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Sorry, still doesn’t work.

Comment: Did you try
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f upgrade`
?

Comment: That did work but I got a different, possibly unrelated error.